# How To Get Value Of Span Class Title Value

Tags: javascript

I would like JS to return the text value of title which is 'lost' from this line of code:

I want to print to console only the text "lost".

I tried the following (which didn't work):

```js
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('_3rAzIK1XDa7ajuyjz8OJkl _12pssoQOCYKCt5amUeIK')[0].getElementsByClassName('title')[0].innerText)
```

```html
<span class="_3rAzIK1XDa7ajuyjz8OJkl _12pssoQOCYKCt5amUeIK" data-qa="text-recent-bet-status" title="lost"><i class="betgames-icon closed"></i></span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`title` isn't a class name, it's an attribute. Use `.getAttribute()` to get its value.

```js
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('_3rAzIK1XDa7ajuyjz8OJkl _12pssoQOCYKCt5amUeIK')[0].getAttribute('title'));
```

```html
<span class="_3rAzIK1XDa7ajuyjz8OJkl _12pssoQOCYKCt5amUeIK" data-qa="text-recent-bet-status" title="lost"><i class="betgames-icon closed"></i></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [**getAttribute()**](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getattribute.asp) to get the value of the `title` attribute of selected DOM element:. Here `title` is an Attribute and not a class.

```js
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('_3rAzIK1XDa7ajuyjz8OJkl _12pssoQOCYKCt5amUeIK')[0].getAttribute('title'))
```

```html
<span class="_3rAzIK1XDa7ajuyjz8OJkl _12pssoQOCYKCt5amUeIK" data-qa="text-recent-bet-status" title="lost"><i class="betgames-icon closed"></i></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns the elements array based on that `className`.

And to get the `title` attribute of the selected element, you can use `getAttribute` function.

```js
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('_3rAzIK1XDa7ajuyjz8OJkl')[0].getAttribute('title'));
```

```html
<span class="_3rAzIK1XDa7ajuyjz8OJkl _12pssoQOCYKCt5amUeIK" data-qa="text-recent-bet-status" title="lost"><i class="betgames-icon closed"></i></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('_3rAzIK1XDa7ajuyjz8OJkl _12pssoQOCYKCt5amUeIK')[0].title)
```

You can directly access default attributes like title or use getAttribute('title') instead.